# Removing red eye from an Image on the client side using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, image, image-processing, codeigniter-2

I have the following html code rendered on my client's browser:

```
<div id="Div">
  <img src="myImage.jpg" id="myImage"/>
</div>
```

This particular image is uploaded by the user and then displayed here.
I need to allow my user to remove any red-eye from this image. I would like to do it without any postback ( I'm using CodeIgniter at the back ). Are there any available libraries for this in JQuery (or plain Javascript) ? If not what could be a good approach ?

Comment: That's a very non-trivial thing you are trying to do.

Comment: :D . So should I let PHP do the processing and just display the result ?

Comment: What's next...? Use javascript to launch nuclear missile? On a serious note, yes you should probably get your server to do image processing for you if it's as complex as removing red eye.

Comment: Thanks guys, just wanted to know if it was possible at all. Now I can go for the server side approach in peace :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot of things that go on in red eye removal

A. Eye Detection

B. Red Eye Region Mapping

C. Fill Color

D. Fuzz

E. Opaque

**My advice**

If not a JOB for Jquery and even PHP  would not remove red eye effectively

**Likely Solution**

1. Get a Jquery area selection script where users can select their red eyes them self ( With this you would be able to get the region (X1 , Y1 , X2 , Y2 , Height , Width )  example http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/
2. Have a simple Color Picker where they can select replacement color ??? Default can be black
3. Send request to `imagemagick` using `exec` in PHP for the red eye removal
4. You can not output your image ...

**EDIT 1**

I was able to help you get a ready command line tool for this JOB

http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php
http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/redeye/index.php

Basic Concept

A. Create a desaturate copy of the input image

B. Perform a fuzzy floodfill to create a mask image

C. Composite the original with the desaturated image using the mask image

D. Apply a morphologic close operation to fill in the specular hole in the mask 
and then create a difference operation to create a new mask of just the hole

E. Apply the new mask to composite the previous result with a full lightness, 
zero saturation version of the original image

Sample Process

```
convert -quiet -regard-warnings "$infile" +repage "$tmpA1"
convert $tmpA1 -modulate $light,$sat,100 $tmpA2
proc=""
for ((i=0; i<np; i++)); do
proc="$proc matte ${pairArray[i]} floodfill"
done
convert $tmpA5 -fuzz $fuzz% -fill none -draw "$proc" \
-fill "rgba(255,255,255,1)" +opaque "rgba(0,0,0,0)" \
-fill "rgba(0,0,0,1)" -opaque "rgba(0,0,0,0)" \
-alpha off -negate $tmpA3
if [ "$dilate" = 0 ]; then
dilation=""
else
dilation="-morphology dilate disk:$dilate"
fi
convert $tmpA1 $tmpA2 $tmpA3 -compose over -composite $tmpA2
convert $tmpA3 \( +clone -morphology close disk:$rad $dilation \) \
-compose difference -composite -auto-level \
-negate -threshold 0 -negate $tmpA4
convert $tmpA2 \( $tmpA1 -modulate 100,0,100 \) $tmpA4 \
-compose over -composite $outfile
```

I hope this helps

Thanks

:)